# WSO2 API properties in custom handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How can I access the API related information like API Properties (defined in publisher) in the WSO2 Custom handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below code. It will print all the messagecontext property key set and their values.

```
        Set propertySet = context.getPropertyKeySet();
    for (Object propertyKey : propertySet) {

        log.info("Key: " + propertyKey.toString() + "| value: "
                + context.getProperty(propertyKey.toString()));
    }
```

Also refer [this](http://lahiruwrites.blogspot.com/2016/07/synapse-properties-available-in-api.html)

Comment: i was searching for this. btw, is there any conflicts in different versions of WSO2 API manager? because i tried to catch REST_FULL_REQUEST_PATH in WSO2 API Manager-2.5.0, but it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message context object to access API information:

```
messageContext.getProperty("api.ut.HTTP_METHOD")
```

Refer [sample](https://github.com/anuruddhal/CustomHandler) for more info.

Comment: `api.ut.HTTP_METHOD` provides only HTTP method. I need API properties that are defined in the API configuration while creating API in publisher.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see handler/mediator can have access to api properties via local registry

When defined in xml configuration it can be like [this](https://stackcheats.github.io/access-api-custom-properties/)

```
<sequence name="custom-sequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <log level="custom">
      <property 
        name="prop"
        expression="get-property('registry', 
          fn:concat(
            'gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/',
            $ctx:api.ut.apiPublisher, '/',
            $ctx:api.ut.api, '/',
            $ctx:api.ut.version, '/',
            'api@api_meta.my_property'
          ))" />
  </log>
</sequence>
```

Also when using property with devportal visibility enabled, then you have to access it via name ended with `__display` for example `api_meta.my_property__display`